# How to fill and finish joints on ceiling between pre-cast concrete planks

Tags: drywall, concrete

They are structural precast planks that form the floor above. I think the line is where the sheets are connected. I found a picture of them at http://ths.gardenweb.com/discussions/2578737/ugly-ceiling-how-to-fix.

My question is, can I fill these gaps with mud or something else in order to have the apperance of one continuous ceiling?

Comment: Would you be open to decorative ceiling tile?  They come in a wide variety of patterns so it doesn't have to be institutional like an office building.

Comment: A common tactic in hotels and such is to fill the seams with a flexible caulk, and then spray the ceiling with acoustic texture. The seams are still visible as depressed lines, but it looks fairly good.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing you can use to fill in the area if yours is like the picture from the site.  Well you can and it could quite possibly look great for a period of time but it will invariable crack in every joint.  Not only due to expansion and contraction but also to movement in the concrete.

You would have to install wood/metal furring strips across the whole ceiling to do this right.  This would be a bit of work since you would need to secure these to concrete.  And then just sink your drywall into the furring strips.  Given that you have the ability to make holes in the ceiling (you are permitted to) this is a rather "cheap" task for a DIYer but very very labor intensive task.

Comment: I was hoping I could use something like drywall mud to fill the gaps. Thanks for letting me know before I wasted my time.

Comment: Complete waste of time.  Maybe someone has some miracle mix that won't crack or another idea but it won't be covered up using normal materials long-term.

Comment: @DMoore What about filling with plaster to make it level and then painting over with an elastic/plastic paint? that paint is intended to stretch, so that it will cover the cracks.

Comment: I think they are latex-based.

Answer (score 0):

There are certainly fillers and paints that would work, the problem is many of them require gravity working in the opposite direction - they are made for floors, not ceilings.  For example self leveling fillers are very thin, they pour on, level out and harden.  I am sure there are acrylic / epoxy based fillers that would work but they are probably expensive and hard to work with.

Just a thought, but you could install a molding over the seams and wind up with a kind of a miniature coffered effect.  That may look nice or may be uglier than the seams, a matter of taste.  (I don't think the seams look bad in that photo, I'd paint it parquet style and pretend it was planned.)

Drywall on furring strips shouldn't be that big of a deal.  The furring strips don't have to be super precise and could probably be shot in (powder actuated fasteners) real quick and easy - depends on the concrete.  If you fur it out you'd have some space to run wiring if you ever wanted to put lights etc. up there.